# Vuejs class doesn't update after ajax request

Tags: vue.js

What I'm trying to do is to highlight a table row after the component has been created or mounted. The playingTrack value is being changed to the id of the current song but the class doesn't change.
The @click function works and changes the class to highlight but what I want is for it to happen when component is mounted taking its value from playingTrack variable.

```
<tr :class="{highlight:track.id == playingTrack}" @click="playingTrack = track.id" v-for="track in tracks">
    <td class="align-middle">
      {{track.title}} <br> <span style="color: grey;">{{track.artist}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
  export default{
    data(){
        return{
            tracks:{},
            album:{},
            playingTrack: undefined
        }
    },
    beforeCreate(){
        Event.$emit('requestCurrentTrack');
        Event.$on('currentTrack', (data) => this.fetchAlbum(data));
    },
    methods:{
        fetchAlbum(data){
            axios.get('/api/album/'+this.id).then((response)=>{
                if(data){
                    this.playingTrack = data.id;
                }
                this.tracks = response.data[0];
                this.album = response.data[1][0];
            });
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Computed Property"

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Here is well-written documentation.

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more on how I could use it in my code. I'm not very familiar with computed properties and don't know how it would solve my problem.